# Manipulating Complex Exponentials

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry, exponential-function

I am trying to show that 
$$
sin(5\pi t) = \frac 12 e^{-j \frac {\pi}2}e^{j5\pi t} - \frac 12 e^{-j \frac {\pi}2}e^{-j5\pi t}
$$

I am aware that 
$$
sin(\theta) = \frac {e^{j\theta} - e^{-j\theta}}{j2}
$$

But if you multiply the top and bottom by $j$, then the answer becomes
$$
sin(5\pi t) = -\frac 12 je^{5\pi t} + \frac 12 je^{-j5\pi t}
$$

I'm really no sure of where to go from here.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Tip: it's standard to use $i$ to represent the square root of $-1$ in mathematics and failing to do so might be confusing to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Euler's identity $e^{ix}=\cos x+i\sin x$

$$e^{j\pi/2}=\cos\dfrac\pi2+j\sin\dfrac\pi2=j$$

$$\implies e^{-j\pi/2}=j^{-1}=-j$$ as $j^2=-1$

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

What you have run into is [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) for complex exponents:

$$e^{j\theta}=\cos(\theta)+j\sin(\theta)$$

Using the identity that $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$ and $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$, we get:

$$e^{-j\theta}=\cos(\theta)-i\sin(\theta)$$

Subtract the two equations, and we get:

$$e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}=2j\sin(\theta)\tag1$$

$$\sin(\theta)=\frac{e^{j\theta}-e^{-j\theta}}{2j}$$

Which is what you started with.

But at step $(1)$, we arrive with your derivation.  And so, that is the explanation I give to you.